Then does not work on Future<DateTime> into DateTime
Then is not recognized on File(file.path).lastModified().
I get the message: Function expressions can't be named.
I need to convert Future<DateTime> into DateTime.
Future DateTime: File(file.path).lastModified()
After conversion, I need to use the string: FileLastModified.toString().
Do you have any ideas or suggestions?
Thank You
Code:
DateTime FileLastModified=DateTime.timestamp();

File(file.path).lastModified().then((value)){
          FileLastModified = value;
});


Why aren't you just using https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-io/File/lastModifiedSync.html ?

I tried it now, and it's still the same issue.

Uh, there's no Future if you use the sync version.  Did you mistakenly try .then with it?

DateTime FileLastModified=DateTime.timestamp();

File(file.path).lastModified().then((value)){
                                           ^
          FileLastModified = value;
});

extra ) here.
